# How to jump to a search in a mapped :normal command?

Tags: vim

What do you need to properly jump to a matched search result?

To reproduce, make a macro with a search in it after you've run `vim -u NONE` to ensure there's no vimrc interfering. You'll need  to make a file with at least 2 lines and put the cursor on the line without the text `TEST_TEXT`.

```
map x :norm gg/TEST_TEXT^MIthis
```

My intention is that when I press `x`, it goes to the top of the file, looks for TEST_TEXT and then puts `this` at the start of the line that matches the search. The `^M` is a literal newline, achieved with the CtrlQ+Enter keypress. What's happening instead is either nothing happens, or the text gets entered on the same line as when I called the macro.

If I just run the `:norm gg/TEST_TEXT^MIthis` command without mapping it to a key, the command executes successfully.

I had an initially longer command involving a separate file and the tcomment plugin, but I've gotten it narrowed down to this.

What is the correct sequence of keys  to pull this off once I've mapped it to a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this mapping:

```
nnoremap x gg/TEST_TEXT<cr>Ithis<esc>
```

note that, if you map `x` on this operation, you lost the original `x` feature.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution, to remove `:norm`.

Comment: Note this will not work correctly in the case that the start of the buffer starts with `TEST_TEXT`. It will instead use the second match.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `^M` concludes the `:normal` Ex command, so your search command is aborted instead of executed. The `Ithis` is then executed outside of `:normal`.

In fact, you don't need `:normal` here at all. And, it's easier and more readable to use the *special key* notation with mappings:

```
:map x gg/TEST_TEXT<CR>Ithis
```

If you really wanted to use `:normal`, you'd have to wrap this in `:execute`, like this:

```
:map x :exe "norm gg/TEST_TEXT\<lt>CR>Ithis"<CR>
```

#### Bonus tips

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Better restrict the mapping to *normal mode*, as in its current form, it won't behave as expected in visual and operator-pending mode: `:nnoremap`
- This clobbers the last search pattern and its highlighting. Use of lower-level functions like `search()` is recommended instead.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, I wasn't aware that `^M` finishes the normal command. Good tip, removing the `:norm`.

Comment: Something else that was missing, which you didn't mention, is that the any ex command (including `:normal`) NEEDS a final `<CR>` to finish it off. This was missing from the mapping in the question and you added it in on your answer using `:execute`. You're right of course that the ^M in the mapping was finishing off the ex command, I missed that and assumed at first it was a matter of actually running the ex command.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this however this is my preferred method:

```
nnoremap x :0/TEST_TEXT/norm! Itest<esc>
```

Explanation:

- `:{range}norm! {cmd}` - execute normal commands, `{cmd}`, on a range of lines,`{range}`.
- `!` on `:normal` means the commands will not be remapped.
- The range `0/TEST_TEXT` start before the first line and then finds the first matching line.

I have a few issues with your current mapping:

- You are not specifying `noremap`. You usually want to use `noremap`
- It would be best to specifiy a mode like normal mode, e.g. `nnoremap`
- It is usually best to use `<cr>` notation with mappings
- You are using `:normal` when your command is already in normal mode but not using any of the `ex` command features, e.g. a range.

For more help see:

```
:h :map
:h :norm
:h range
```